# Gemfile loading twice / rvm --default not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

### Gemfile

Every time I'm running a command in my terminal that requires my Gemfile, it gets loaded twice. Such as `rails server`, `rails console`, `bundle install`, ... etc

Adding `puts "gemfile loading?"`at the end of my Gemfile cleary show that:

#### Output from my shell:

```
gemfile loading?
/Users/AnsPoluke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
gemfile loading?
/Users/AnsPoluke/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
```

I have no idea what the error code is telling me... Bonusquestion! ;)

### RVM

Additionally, every time I open a new shell I have to reconfigure what ruby version I'm using, even though I have used `rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3`plenty of times.

running `rvm list` in any new shell

```
ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]
```

The default is recognised correctly, but running `ruby -v` outputs

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

#### Using:

- oh-my-zhs
- rails 3.2.10
- rvm 1.17.6

Somehow I feel that these problems may be linked together... Appreciate your help!

Comment: Bonus question answer: it is saying that you might have too much rights on /usr/local/bin path. Try running `chmod 644 /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Awsome, it worked! :) Thanks allot

Comment: this were in fact 3 questions, please open a new ticket per question!

Comment: opening a ticket == asking a question?

I appreciate you mentioning this: could you maybe send me a link to some statement of stackoverflow that mentions this? I couldn't find anything in the FAQ...

Comment: please have a look on the rules http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rails` is known from multiple execution of `bundler`, in this case it can be extra call caused by `rubygems-bundler` you can disable it temporarily with:

```
NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 rails s
```

then check if rails is properly detecting double `bundle exec` with:

```
NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 bundle exec rails s
```

if that works open a ticket for `rubygems-bundler` here: https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler

---

as for the default ruby issue - it is known problem with oh-my-zsh => https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/1359 you need to remove hardcoded `PATH=` with no `$PATH` from `~/.zshrc`

You can also try latest version of RVM, it has a trick to extra fix and sort `PATH` ... but it's only a hack to the real problem is the hardcoded `PATH=` in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks alot! The zsh problem worked like a charm ^^ No need to use `rvm --default` each time I open up a terminal.

`NOEXEC_DISBALE=1 rails s` worked aswell! The gemfile only got loaded once... Including `bundle exec` made it load 4 times, not sure what happened there...

Anyhow, I'll gladly accept your answer! Would it be better to reduce  both my question aswell as your answer to the `zsh`/ `rvm`-problem?

I can then ask new questions to solve the other problems... Please add in your 2 cents :)

Comment: just open a ticket for https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler about the double execution of rails - I will investigate and present a fix for it in `rubygems-bundler`